# Draw Line when Button is pressed Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton

I have some problem drawing a simple line to a `Frame` through a `JButton`.
The problem occurs only when I do this with a `JButton`. 
If I directly use the `JPanel` inside the `Frame`, everything is OK.

`JFrame`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

    public Fenetre(){
        super("Test");
        init();
        pack();
        setSize(200,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Draw line");

        button.addActionListener((e)->{
            Pane s = new Pane();
            panel.add(s);
            s.repaint();
        });

        panel.setBackground(new Color(149,222,205));

        add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Fenetre();
    }

}
```

And the `JPanel` with `paintComponents()`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Pane extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.drawLine(0,20,100,20);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);` (less 2 's' characters). 2) Adding components at run-time requires special handling. Why not use a `CardLayout` instead? 3) *"If you have some references to learn Swing I'm interested."* Requesting off-site resources is off-topic for SO, but since it is not the main question, will answer in a comment. See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Comment: `panel.add(s);` should be followed by `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()`, but you're still going to be disappointed with the results

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"you're still going to be disappointed"* Ooh, nicely spotted! Do you prefer a size? (Or is it something different again?)

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, missing sizing hints is my focus

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It run correctly now !
I think i need more practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of issues jump out at me immediately:

1. You should be using `paintComponent`, not `paintComponents` (note the `s` at the end), you're too high up in the paint chain. There's also no need for either method to be `public`, no one outside the class should be calling it.
2. `Pane` provides no sizing hints, so it's "default" size will be `0x0`

Instead, it should look more like...

```
public class Pane extends JPanel {

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 40);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(0,20,100,20);
    }
}
```

When adding components, Swing is lazy.  It won't run a layout/paint pass until it has to or you ask it to.  This is an optimisation, as you may add many components before needing to perform a layout pass.

To request a layout pass, call `revalidate` on the top level container you've updated.  As a general rule of thumb, if you call `revalidate`, you should also call `repaint` to request a new paint pass as well.

```
public class Fenetre extends JFrame {

    public Fenetre(){
        super("Test");
        init();
        //pack();
        setSize(200,200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("Draw line");

        button.addActionListener((e)->{
            Pane s = new Pane();
            panel.add(s);
            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();
            //s.repaint();
        });

        panel.setBackground(new Color(149,222,205));

        add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Fenetre();
    }

}
```

That should at least get your `panel` to show up now

Comment: I didn't noticed the 's' :S
revalidate() solved my problem, thank you !